# Describing the image and nullspace of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be the space of all continuous functions on $[a,b$]. Define the map $T$ according to
$$T[f](x)=\int_a^b f(t) \sin(x-t) \mathrm{d} t. $$
I want describe the image and kernel (nullspace) of this map. 
In order to do this, I've first noticed that
$$T[f](x)=\left(-\int_a^b f(t) \sin(t) \mathrm{d} t \right) \cos(x)+\left( \int_a^b f(t) \cos(t) \right) \sin(x) .$$
This means that the image $T[V]$ is a subspace of the space spanned by $\{ \cos(x),\sin(x)\}$. The kernel consists of all functions $f$ such that
$$\int_a^b f(t) \sin(t) \mathrm{d}t=\int_a^b f(t) \cos(t) \mathrm{d} t=0. $$
I'd like some help on showing that $T[V]=\operatorname{span} \{\cos(x),\sin(x)\}$, and perhaps getting a clearer characterization of the kernel. Notice that if $[a,b]=[-\pi,\pi]$ we can use the orthogonality of $\sin$ and $\cos$, but I'm interested in a general interval. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since $T$ is linear, to prove that $T[V]=\operatorname{span} \{\cos(x),\sin(x)\}$ it is enough to find functions $f$ and $g$ such that $T[f]=\cos$, $T[g]=\sin$. You can try functions of the form $f(x)=A\,x+B$. This will give a system of two equations in the two unknowns $A$ and $B$ (except perhaps for a excepcional set of values $a$ and $b$.)